# stream:verify is failing with "The caller does not have permission" error

Tags: python, secevents

My security event receiver is set up and I'm at [this step](https://developers.google.com/identity/risc#test_stream) trying to test that it actually works. I've copied the code from the example almost exactly, but my script is resulting in an error.

Here's my code:

```py
import requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'token.json',
    scopes=[
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/risc.verify',
    ])

authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
stream_verify_endpoint = 'https://risc.googleapis.com/v1beta/stream:verify'
state = {'state': 'Test token requested.'}

try:
  response = authed_session.post(stream_verify_endpoint, json=state)
  response.raise_for_status()  # Raise exception for unsuccessful requests
except requests.HTTPError as e:
  print(e.response.text)
```

And here's the response text:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
        "detail": "[ORIGINAL ERROR] generic::permission_denied: com.google.apps.framework.request.ForbiddenException: RISC disabled for project number [my project number]"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

"The caller does not have permission" is not listed as a possible 403 response in [the error response reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/risc#error_codes). The RISC API is absolutely enabled for the given project ID. The service account for `token.json` is brand new and has Editor permissions. The receiver is able to be registered just fine. Why can I not send test/verify security events?

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake, I had disabled my receiver endpoint and forgotten about doing so.

If anyone is having the same issue, simply re-enable the endpoint as described here: https://developers.google.com/identity/risc#stop_and_resume_the_event_stream